# Flex. Incorrect XML deserialization. & (&amp;) and other special chars

Tags: apache-flex

I'm a newbie in Flex and I encountered the following problem.

When deserializing an XML with FlexXB I get different results from the tag and it's attributes.

**For example:**

```
<line text="A&amp;amp;B">C&amp;amp;D</line>
```

After deserialization I expect

```
text: A&amp;B
line: C&amp;D
```

but as a result I get

```
text: A&amp;B
line: C&amp;amp;D
```

After sources have been investigated I found that in XmlMemberSerializer.as used

> child.toXMLString();

but in XmlAttributeSerializer.as

> value = valueXML[0];

which is equivalent to .toString();

I don't understand whether it is correct or not. And I need help how to get expected results in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me, based on your investigation, the returned result is correct. However if this was intentionally done by the creator of FlexXB only he knows. You could open an issue and see if the owner responds.

Answer (score 0):

Google developers fixed this issue in r744 revision. [XmlMemberSerializer.as diff](https://code.google.com/p/flexxb/source/diff?spec=svn744&r=744&format=side&path=/trunk/FlexXB/FlexXB/src/main/flex/com/googlecode/flexxb/xml/serializer/XmlMemberSerializer.as)